# How to remove the last few segments of Emit IL at runtime

Tags: c#, cil, emit

How to remove the last few segments of Emit IL at runtime

I tried to modify some logic in a thousand lines of code, I want to use the rollback IL way to add new logic, avoid changing the previous code.

#### simple e.g :

I hope to remove the last few segments of Emit IL and then emit new il when `isSomeLogic` is true.

```
void Main()
{
    DynamicMethod methodbuilder = new DynamicMethod("Deserialize" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), typeof(void), null);
    var il = methodbuilder.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello World");
    Type[] types = new Type[1]{typeof(string)};
    MethodInfo method = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", types);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    // do some thing...
    var isSomeLogic = true;
    if( isSomeLogic ){
        //remove the il OpCodes.Ret and add new logic Emit
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }

    var func = (Action)methodbuilder.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
    func();
}
```

Comment: Since this is obviously emitted at run-time why not just postpone the `OpCodes.Ret` emit until you know whether you want to emit more code before returning?

Comment: thanks, I tried to modify some logic in a thousand lines of code, I want to use the rollback IL way to add new logic, avoid changing the previous code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ILGenerator` is forwards only. You can't *remove* opcodes that you've added. Instead, just... don't add them? Alternatively, you can use `Label` and jump operations; the `Ret` doesn't need to be at the *end* of a method; the following is perfectly valid, as long as the stack is at the correct height at the ret, and the stack height is the same for all paths to a particular location.

- do things
- jump to X
- label: Y
- do more things
- ret
- label: X
- do even more things
- jump to Y

Comment: thanks,i'll tag this as answer later , and  this I tried to modify some logic in a thousand lines of code, I want to use the rollback IL way to add new logic, avoid changing the previous code.

Comment: @ITWeiHan my advice: change the previous code to make it fit the scenario; IL is hard enough to get right *anyway*; the last thing you want to do is hack in something that doesn't really fit well; trust me: I've been there (I do "quite a lot" of IL-emit)

Comment: thanks ! I will use your way, I have seen Dapper IL writing, it is really amazing.

Comment: @ITWeiHan Dapper's IL writing is frankly crude and badly structured; I'm tempted to rip it out and start again; protobuf-net has *much* more sensible emit